# Which on is faster in java, removing and adding an element or evaluate if i have to?

Tags: java, performance, list

I have a 2D array containing lists, the lists are no longer than 3 elements.
I periodically have to move elements from one list to another. An element can only be in one of the lists. When moving an element, which one is faster?
To first calculate which list should the element be in, check if the list has that element, and if yes then do nothing, but if it doesn't, then remove if from the old list and add it to the new one.
Or to remove it from the list it is in and then add it to another or the same list, regardless if it should have been moved or not.

Comment: This isn't clear; your two alternatives don't sound equivalent.  Can you add some illustrative code examples?

Comment: can you shed some more light on why you're keeping small lists this way? is there a finite number of lists and elements? what's the core problem? you're looking at this from a very implementation point of view without showing any code, you might be better coming at the problem from a different angle.

Comment: The size of the lists varies, and the lists do not always contain 3 elements, but theorically that is a maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using ArrayList with size 3 and define it like:

```
List<String> oldList = new ArrayList<String>(3);
Set<String> myNewStringSet = new HashSet<String>();
```

and you could use contains method like:

```
if (!myList.contains("myElement")) {
    //No indeed its not there add it to new myNewStringSet  that you are creating
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd option won't work, since it would cause your lists to contain duplicates. If you add an element to a list that already contains that element, it will now contain that element twice. And if later you try to remove that element from that list using `remove(Object)`, you'll only remove one of the two occurences of the element, so the list would still contain that element.

That second option can only work with `Set`s.

Comment: There would not be any duplicates in the list since i first remove it, then add it.

Comment: But you said you are not checking if the element is in the list prior to adding it, which implies it could already be in the list.

Comment: An element can only be in a single list at any given time.

Comment: I misunderstood the question

Comment: Nope @Eran you understood it right. Probably OP didn't explain it clear.

Comment: I'm  sorry for an confusion, I'll try better when asking something again.